# negative lettee-spacing cutting off text

Tags: html, css

I have the following text:

[image]

Whenever I try to add `letter-spacing: -1px` the text renders properly but it also gets cut by a couple of pixels on the right. This happens on Webkit.

[image]

I've trying adjusting it with margins and paddings but with no results. Any help?

Comment: looks beautiful. What font?

Comment: have u tried this link http://blog.room34.com/archives/4986

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `overflow: scroll` just to make sure its not a size cutoff issue.

Additionally using something like chrome developer tools or firebug to view the elements on mouse however helps with visually hidden padding / margin / border / size issues.

Comment: i tried but it didn't change. also, inspecting the element with chrome tools doesn't reveal any hidden issue.

Comment: seems like adding padding: -1px added the extra space needed. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just run into this problem myself. I don't know why exactly this happening but adding padding-right would help.

In my case it's:

```
.text-element {letter-spacing: -7px; padding-right: 7px;}
```